# A script to switch my Display 2 adaptor properties mode in a click for my ultrawide monitor?

Tags: display, resolution, screen-resolution, multiple-monitors, multi-window

I am currently using an ultrawide monitor of 3840x1080 but when I switch to 2Window mode, I.E PS5 display on one side of the screen while my desktop remain on the right side of the screen, the desktop side of the screen remains in 3840x1080 resolution so its very squished.

In order to rectify that I have to keep manually accessing my,

1. Advanced Display Settings
2. Display Adaptor Properties ->
3. Change from "3840 by 1080, True Color (32bit), 60 Hertz" to "1920 by 1080, True Color (32 bit), 120 Hertz"
4. Vice versa when I'm done to switch back the resolution.

I'm trying to make a script that can expedite the process in a click but to no avail.

The resources online is a bit lacking in my case and I'm very new to this so I'm hoping someone can help. Thanks in advance!

The furthest I've gotten was use "AlbertoMGV/ScreenResolutionChanger" on GitHub but it does not change to mode for my display 2 so it is still in 3840x1080.